# How to get the row number of an element using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, where-clause, window-functions

How can I get the row number of an element?

Example Data

```
id   name   age
8347 Jacob  65
3645 Jerico 67
3243 Michel 34
```

How can I get the row number of age 67?
row number 2

Comment: Row number is a rather meaningless concept in relational databases. But you could say "I want to know who is oldest, who is second oldest, and who is youngest"

Comment: Is age a unique field? Do you want all occurrences? or the first one? can we order by any column?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception: sql table represents *unordered* sets of rows. There is no inherent ordering in the data. If you do not use an `order by` clause, then the order in which rows are returned is not deterministic.

So, to start with, you need to order your records. Let's assume that you want to order them by `id` (it seems to be a unique column, which is good for ordering since it avoids ties). If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` to rank the records:

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from mytable t) t
where age = 67
```

This record with age 67 will be assigned row number 2, since that's its position when data is sorted by `id`. If you had several records with age 67, they would all show in the resultset, along with their associated row number.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things this is not a MySQL function rather SQL, as explained in @Strawberry's comment row number is meaningless.

This question looks similar to what you are trying to achieve so please take a look! [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: You could instead flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the tip :)